# Using sql server alias via management studio on another computer

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I setup alias in sql configuration manager, then on the same server, via management studio I can use the alias name to connect to the server.

However, on another computer when I open management studio, then can I use the alias name to connect? My understanding is that the SQL server IP or server name can be used as that is recorded in the DNS. Can alias work and if yes, then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, aliases are local to the client machine. Use DNS if you want a central configuration place.